# Fire RowEditEnding event by Pressing Escape Key

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, events

When any cell is editing in WPF Datagrid, If I Press Escape the CellEditEnding Event Fires. Instead I want to fire RowEditEnding.

I know that when I press Escape key once, CellEditEnding event fires and when I press Escape Key second time, RowEditEnding event fires. But I don't want this behavior. I want that when I press Escape key First time, I want to fire RowEditEnding event.

Comment: Why you don't fire `RowEditEnding` when `CellEditEnding` fired ?

Comment: please, show XAML of `DataGrid` and a way of binding to `DataGrid`(`DataTable` or `ObservableCollection`)

Comment: @wajeeh can you please give me an example?

Comment: something like `function onCellEditEnding(args..){ // fire RowEditEnding()  }`, is that your problem ?

Comment: @wajeeh I don't know how to do that because the event args parameter is different for CellEditEnding and RowEditEnding. So, what do I pass to the second parameter. Also in RowEditEnding I am using its second parameter, so I cant pass null

Comment: You can pass `null` value and then you have to check for it `if(param == null) { //called programmatically } else { // your previous code }`

Comment: I do not have `C#` IDE right now, So I can not test it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From MSDN website take a look at [DataGridCellEditEndingEventArgs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagridcelleditendingeventargs(v=vs.110).aspx) and [DataGridRowEditEndingEventArgs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagridroweditendingeventargs(v=vs.110).aspx)

So you can build a new `EventArg` and pass it to the second method.

```
private void CellEditEnding(object sender, DataGridCellEditEndingEventArgs e) {
    DataGridRowEditEndingEventArgs arg = new DataGridRowEditEndingEventArgs(e.Row, e.EditAction);
    OnRowEditEnding(sender, arg);
}
```

Then

```
private void OnRowEditEnding(object sender, DataGridRowEditEndingEventArgs e) {
    // your code
}
```

Maybe there is some error because I do not have `C#` IDE right now.

Note that you can add some check to distinguish from where the method called.

Comment: Thank you for answering. I was just confused & you made it so easy.

Comment: You are welcome, feel free to edit the answer if it contains typo error. @Vishal